# Input string was not in a correct format(

Tags: c#, string, class, input

I'm currenstly learning C# and try to implement a class "Polynomial" using dynamic list. But when I compile an error occurs. It's written that input string was not in a correct format.
Thanks you for your help in advance.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Polynom
    {
        class S
        {
            public int power;
            public int koef;
            public S next;

            public S()
            {
                power = 0;
                koef = 0;
                next = null;
            }

            public S(int p, int k)
            {
                power = p;
                koef = k;
                next = null;
            }
        }

        private int n;
        private S first;

        public Polynom()
        {
            n = 0;
            first = null;
        }

        public Polynom(int nn)
        {
            n = nn;
            if (first == null)
            {
                first = new S();
                first.power = n - 1;
                first.next = null;
            }
            else
            {
                S temp = new S();
                temp.power = n - 1;
                temp.next = first;
                first = temp;
            }
            ++this.n;
        }

        public void Input()
        {
            n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            S temp = new S();
            first = temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                temp.power = i;
                temp.koef = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                temp.next = new S();
                temp = temp.next;
                if (i != n - 1)
                    temp = new S();
            }
        }

        public void Output()
        {
            S temp = first;
            while (temp != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} x^ {1} +", temp.koef, temp.power);
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Polynom t = new Polynom();
            t.Input();
            t.Output();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` are you feeding it an `int`?

Comment: Please post only the code that is relevant to your issue, not the whole of it. Also, if an exception occurs, please add in your description the associated line.

Comment: Exactly where u r getting error?

Comment: Welcome to SO and to C#. Learning to understand compiler and runtime errors (and the difference between them) are about the start of learning to program. This runtime error occurs on a given line. Inspect which method throws and what input you provide.

Comment: More proper place to ask such kind of question/assistance is in [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you want help we at the very least need to know what the error is and what line it is occurring on.

Comment: n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 0):

Your making a mistake when parsing the number. In your code you expect the user to enter something that actually is a number but don´t tell the program what to do if this is not the case. Rewrite your input function to something like this (note that the below is not the shortest way to write it, but atleast its easy to read)

```
public void Input()
        {
            bool hasNumber = false;
            while (!hasNumber)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                try
                {
                    n = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                    hasNumber = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input + " Is not a number");
                }
            }
            //n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            S temp = new S();
            first = temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                temp.power = i;
                temp.koef = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //<< you'll have to fix this one yourself
                temp.next = new S();
                temp = temp.next;
                if (i != n - 1)
                    temp = new S();
            }
        }
```

Please also note the comments below your question as they contain some pointers about how to ask a question on stackoverflow